# Autoreset circuit for arduino - how I think it works

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

HI I wanted to ask the resistor and capacitor combination within the black circle, it forms an rc constant right? Am I correct in assuming when the chip is powered up, the capacitor is charged up.  The capacitor is discharged when the reset line i spuled low, thereby toggling the DTR pin on ftdi chip?  Wouldn't the voltage applied to the capacitor also affect how fast it charges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking about it all backwards.

The capacitor is discharged when you power up, as both sides are at +5V, so there is no potential difference.

When the serial port is opened by the PC the DTR line is pulled low by the FTDI chip causing a potential difference, and the capacitor to charge up.  This causes brief a low pulse on the RESET side of the capacitor resetting the Atmel chip.

[image: Arduino reset]

(Image courtesy of [Nick Gammon](http://www.gammon.com.au) - RTS is DTR in your circuit [either can be used])

The value of the capacitor and resistor define how long the capacitor takes to charge up - the voltage has nothing to do with it.  However, the voltage applied to it does affect how long it takes to reach a different specific voltage - for example (made up figures here), apply 5V to it and it takes 1 second to reach 5V.  Apply 15V and it takes 1 second to reach 15V, so it would take only a fraction of that to reach 5V - but it would then continue past that 5V until it reaches 15V, which still takes a second.

Comment: OK. so that brief reset I would need a scope to see yes? I wouldn't be able to see it using my cheap multimeter? I would of just used my scope but it's in the garage and it's bloody cold in manchester. So i was kind of right except other way round

Comment: It's not so warm down in Hereford either... ;)  Yes, you'd need a scope to see it.

Comment: Nick Gammon's already done it for you though: http://www.gammon.com.au/images/Arduino/Minimal_Arduino11.jpg

Comment: thanks I suspect there's something fishy going on because I can upload sketches @5v but not 3.3v it's weird. There's like 1mv of ripple on the supply. Clean as a whistle.

Comment: Can you upload sketches if you manually press the reset button just as avrdude's about to execute?

Comment: doesn't look like it. I've even reflashed the bootloader so it doesn't have a sketch to boot into. nope